# When I run this piece of code, it will loop over 3000 times

Tags: python

I just tried to run and play with some def to train myself, accidently 
when I call this function here and there, it loops over and over until reach 3000 times.
why counting 3000 times, and stop.

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)
    print_no_thing()


def print_no_thing():
    print ("No thing ")
    print_two_again("me and ", "you")

def print_two_again(arg1,arg2):
    print "arg1:%r, arg: %r" %(arg1,arg2)
    print_two("pack","packer")

print_two_again("cool", "cooler")
```

Comment: Cool. Do you have a question? Also consider fixing your formatting so we can read it (select the text and hit ctrl-k)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the problem is that you don't want to loop, you need have what is called a `terminal condition`. Currently:

- `print_two_again` calls `print_two`
- `print_two` calls `print_no_thing`
- `print_no_thing` calls `print_two_again`

There are no `conditional clauses` so the functions will continue to call each other and never stop. You need to instrument something that will cause it to quit. There are two ways of doing this:

- Don't have your last function call your first function.
- Keep track of how many times you're looping and eventually stop.

For the first:

```
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)
    print_no_thing()


def print_no_thing():
    print ("No thing ")

def print_two_again(arg1,arg2):
    print "arg1:%r, arg: %r" %(arg1,arg2)
    print_two("pack","packer")

print_two_again("cool", "cooler")
```

For the second:

```
# Note that you shouldn't actually use global variables, but this is clear for demonstration purposes
max_loops = 100
current_loops = 0

def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" %(arg1, arg2)
    print_no_thing()


def print_no_thing():
    print ("No thing ")
    if max_loops > current_loops:
        current_loops += 1
        print_two_again("me and ", "you")

def print_two_again(arg1,arg2):
    print "arg1:%r, arg: %r" %(arg1,arg2)
    print_two("pack","packer")

print_two_again("cool", "cooler")
```

The reason it is currently stopping at three thousand is that you're hitting the maximum recursion depth for Python. Each function will create a new 'stack frame', and because you are never returning from your functions (only calling new functions), you are only ever adding new stack frames. Eventually you will run out (when you reach your `maximum recursion depth`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth) for more.

Note that while it's possible to play with the maximum recursion depth, it's not recommended. `3000` is far beyond what you should need for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: "Terminal condition" sounds like something a doctor would inform me of... I've always heard it being called a "stop condition"...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Fair enough, but I learned it as a `terminal condition` or `termination condition`, or `base case` (if you're actually doing recursion).

Comment: Heh, okay. Programmer humour I guess ;-)

Comment: `dark` does have the same number of letters as `code`, after all... ;-)